# JavaFXML include FXML change upper controller

Tags: java, javafx, inner-classes, fxml, nested

I have a small question.
I have a Menu.FXML which has a Controller (MenuController).
Inside the Menu.FXML I Include another .FXMl (Inner.FXML) and it includes a Label.
The Inner.FXML has a MouseClick event handler, so when I Click the Inner.FXML it does something, I want my Inner.FXML mouse listener to change the text which is inside the Menu.FXML.
How can I do this?
Thank you very much.

[CODE]

```
public class Main extends Application{

 @Override
 public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
     Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Menu.fxml"));

     Scene scene = new Scene(root);

     stage.setScene(scene);
     stage.show();
 }
}
```

InnerController:

```
public class InnerController implements Initializable {
    public void buttonClick(ActionEvent event){
        System.out.println("change label!");
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
   }    
}
```

Menu FXML:

```
<VBox maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="nestedcontroller.MenuController">
   <children>
      <Label text="Label" />
      <fx:include source="Inner.fxml" />
   </children>
</VBox>
```

InnerFXML.

```
<Pane fx:id="pane" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" style="-fx-background-color: green;" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="nestedcontroller.InnerController">
   <children>
      <Button layoutX="271.0" layoutY="187.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#buttonClick" text="Button" />
   </children>
</Pane>
```

Comment: Please post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: So what do you actually want the button to do? Change the text of a label? What are you changing it to?

Comment: I want the button from the InnerFXML to change the text of the Label which is inside the Menu.FXML to something different, like for now it's oke if it just changes to "monday". @James_D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create and observable string property in the `InnerContoller` and set it from the button's handler. Then observe the property from the outer controller.

```
public class InnerController {

    private final ReadOnlyStringWrapper text = new ReadOnlyStringWrapper();

    public ReadOnlyStringProperty textProperty() { 
        return text.getReadOnlyProperty() ;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text.get();
    }

    public void buttonClick(ActionEvent event){
        System.out.println("change label!");
        text.set("Hello world");
    }


    public void initialize() {
   }    
}
```

Then add an `fx:id` to your `fx:include`:

```
<VBox maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="nestedcontroller.MenuController">
   <children>
      <Label text="Label" fx:id="label" />
      <fx:include source="Inner.fxml" fx:id="innerPane" />
   </children>
</VBox>
```

And then in the `MenuController` just observe the property:

```
public class MenuController {
    @FXML
    private Label label ;
    @FXML
    private InnerController innerPaneController ;

    public void initialize() {
        innerPaneController.textProperty().addListener((obs, oldText, newText) -> 
            label.setText(newText));
        // or just label.textProperty().bind(innerPaneController.textProperty());
    }
}
```

See the [FXML documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#nested_controllers) for details.